# how to open multi Universes in SAP BusinessObjects Designer with Excel VBA Code?

Tags: excel, vba, business-objects

I have several universe files ended with '.unv' extension.
Using Excel macro and Visual Basic Application(VBA), I could execute SAP BusinessObjects Universe Designer program in Excel. But different from "open program" in Windows, opened Designer program by Excel only allows me to open 1 universe file at once.

So I want to ask you is there a way to open universe files more than two, but only with VBA code.

This is part of my code I used:

```
    Dim DesApp As Designer.Application
    Dim Univ As Designer.Universe

    Set DesApp = New Designer.Application
    
    DesApp.Window.State = dsMaximized
    DesApp.Visible = True
    Application.StatusBar = "Logging in..."
    Call DesApp.Logon("id","pw","servername","Enterprise")

    'open a universe
    Application.StatusBar = "Opening universe..."
    Set Univ = DesApp.Universes.Open
```